# Setter for custom view attribute

Tags: android, objectanimator

I have got a custom View, called `ColoredCircle` . It got an `attr` called "circlecolor".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="ColoredCircle">
    <attr name="circlecolor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

According to Google, [Creating a View Class](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html), my setter should look like this:

```
public void setCircleColor(int color){
    this.color = color;
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}
```

This setter works as expected if i call it directly, but i want to call the setter with an `ObjectAnimator`. According to Google, [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html), it should work with my setter.

*"The object property that you are animating must have a setter function (in camel case) in the form of `set<PropertyName>()`. Because the `ObjectAnimator` automatically updates the property during animation, it must be able to access the property with this setter method. For example, if the property name is foo, you need to have a setFoo() method."*

But this call gets ignored completely:

```
ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(coloredCircle, 
"circlecolor", new ArgbEvaluator(), coloredCircle.getColor(), newColor);
colorFade.setDuration(300);
colorFade.start();
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: "circlecolor" -> "circleColor", `ofObject` method uses wrong property name

Comment: since attr's name is `circlecolor` obviously method should be named `setCirclecolor`

Comment: i thank you for your precious time